# How to stub methods in a controller that has a shared scope with a directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm testing the controller of a directive that has scope set to false in the directive definition object. A method from the 'parent' controller is called from the directive controller - I am unable to stub this method as I have no access to it from my directive's controller's test file though - what is the best procedure for dealing with this situation?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-define the known methods and set them to `angular.noop`:

```
function ChildController() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.parentMethod1 = angular.noop;
    _this.parentMethod2 = angular.noop;

    _this.childMethod = function() {
        // do some stuff
    };
}
```

Then you can create an `init` method on the child that is called during `link` that replaces the methods with the parent methods if the parent is there:

```
// directive definition
.directive('myDirective', function myDirective() {
    return {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: ChildController,
        controlelrAs: 'childController',
        require: ['childController', '^parentController'],
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
            // controllers[0] = childController
            // controllers[1] = parentController
            controllers[0].init(controllers[1]);
        }
    };
});

// child controller
function ChildController() {
    // ...same as above...
    _this.init = function(parentController) {
        _this.parentMethod1 = parentController.parentMethod1;
        _this.parentMethod2 = parentController.parentMethod2;
    };
}
```

You could also define the controller using `.controller` to make testing simpler (without needing to create the directive with a mock `parentController`). But this should get what you described done.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply - I'm getting 'Missing Required Controller' errors from my directive though, so something isn't quite right. I'm going to have a think and try a different tack I think.

Comment: i may be wrong on not needing to mock out the parent controller. try doing that.